# Projecting urban political boundary files onto U.S. Census blocks QGIS -- Cannot get them to map correctly

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I am trying to project cities' political boundaries (each city is its own shapefile) over a national Census geography layer of Census block groups in QGIS. I know reprojection questions have been answered ad nauseum here regarding how to set the CRS for a project and for each shapefile therein. I have followed all of those directions and have set the CRS appropriately as far as I can tell, but every time I try build my map, my city geographies wind up in a tiny speck of space somewhere in (I think) Oklahoma. The desired (and applied) CRS for all files and the project is WGS 84 EPSG:4326.

Example files causing issues:
New York City: https://www1.nyc.gov/assets/planning/download/zip/data-maps/open-data/nycc_20a.zip
Austin, Texas: https://data.austintexas.gov/Locations-and-Maps/Council-Districts-Fill/hdpc-ysmz
NHGIS Block Group file can be obtained at https://www.nhgis.org/. (I don't believe I'm permitted to reproduce or share the file, but it's publicly accessible.)

EDIT w/ SOLUTION: 
The problem was apparently caused by manipulations I'd done to the city-level files, creating intersections which I was then trying to project onto the national map. Re-downloading the original files, placing them as raw QGIS layers in a new project, and setting the project CRS to WGS 84 EPSG:4326 solved the problem.

Comment: I see no issues with these files. My guess is that you overwrote the CRS of you files by using the "Set CRS" function, which caused your alignment problems. I suggest to just start over with the original files, and to change the CRS, you should use "Save As..." and choose your desired CRS there. This will create a new layer with properly transformed coordinates.

Comment: The problem persists for me. Is there some reason QGIS itself would be buggy? I've done the following multiple times, with the national block group file and the cities' files (I've tried Albuquerque and Oklahoma City in addition to the aforementioned NYC and Austin files): (1) Add Layer>Add Vector Layer>select and add>right click on the layer>Export>Save Features As>Set CRS>Save>Reload New file. Layers' properties say they're projected in the correct CRS but they turn into micro areas in the middle of the national block group layer. I also tried using project "Save As" and set project CRS.

Comment: Did you redownload the files? For me they show up correctly, and I can save them with a new coordinate system without problem. If you add all the original layers together in a new project, without doing anything else, do they show up correctly relative to each other? Also, when you say "...>Set CRS>...", do you mean you choose WGS84 EPSG 4326 in the Save Vector Layer As dialog box?

Comment: I have downloaded the New York shapefile and its geometries are spatialy well defined in New York. You can make a map with all layers defined in different CRS. So, do not change the CRS of the layers nor reproject them. Just set the CRS of the map, i.e. of the project. There is a datum transformation to take into account if the project CRS will not NAD83 datum based, but no one of any available datum transformation from NAD83 to, e.g., WGS84, will move New York to Oklahoma.I don't know if the national block group geometries coordinates are well defined.

Comment: Thank you both for the guidance. I can confirm that on re-downloading and placing the shape files together without manipulating the CRS individually, they overlay properly. I believe my error was I had used intersections I'd made with local Census geographies (because I need to do a number of spatial joins and intersections to calculate demographic reallocations) and something about those manipulations was screwing up the projection. I will edit my OP to reflect that this was due to user error and clarify my mistake.